# Cannot retrieve sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Am trying to retreive data from a sharedpreference file.

Am getting an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'getSharedPreferences'"

Any help fixing this so i can get the string from the preference?

Am doing this as in each activity it is using its own shared preference, one for chest, one for arm etc. so data saved is specific to each activity and doesnt get overwritten hence am not using a default sharedpreference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        SharedPreferences chestPreference = arg0.getContext().getSharedPreferences("ChestWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String newweight =  chestPreference.getString("storednewweight", "");
```

Comment: check the edit, (I hadn't noticed your  getSharedPreferences usage all that well first time around)

Comment: I managed to fix it myself doing this:
SharedPreferences chestPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ChestWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

Inside `View.OnClickListener` `this` points to `View.OnClickListener`object.

Instead use:

```
SharedPreferences chestPreference = MyActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("ChestWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Replace `MyActivity` with you activity name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences chestPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ChestWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

`getSharedPreferences()` is a method. (You are calling `getSharedPreferences` as a variable)

`SharedPreferences chestPreference = getSharedPreferences().getString("ChestWeightPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`